# PHP and Mysql : Should i use long pollog or Server-Sent Events?

Tags: php, mysql, server-sent-events, long-polling

I have a website with a lot of trafic. Currently I use long polling only for the chat section. But now I want to send real time notifications all over the site. So i will create another long polling for those notifications.

Someone talk about SSE(Server-Sent Event)... but i found some  informations to not use SSE with PHP and MySQL ? Is that true ?

Note that this situation will be temporary, because I will be using Socket.io in 1 or 2 months... so temporarily, should I use long polling or SSE?

Is there a better one to not overload the server

Thank you so much

Pascal

Comment: IMHO it's probably not worth re-writing and re-testing just for 1 or 2 months of use, unless you're having really severe and urgent problems currently. But it's just my view. It's really up to you. And opinion-based / discussion questions are specifically off-topic on Stackoverflow.

Comment: `i found some informations to not use SSE with PHP and MySQL`...what did you find? We don't know what issue was raised or what the justification for this assertion was, so we can't really comment on that. Do you have any links?

Comment: Thank you for your messages. I appreciate it. Yes i have a link, it is on YouTube here the link  https://youtu.be/ysQ2jirkHk8?t=31     thank you

Comment: Also, he doesnt explain why he's telling that...

Comment: Well the disclaimer is specific to using Shared Hosting accounts, where you have a low number of simultaneous users allowed at once (and of course an open connection to an SSE stream would count as one simultaneous user, because it keeps a PHP process running).

Comment: Me i have dedicated server... but when he talk about 'Apache server and PHP+MySQL are not ideal for SSE' is he talking on a shared server ? Or simply it is not good to use SSE with PHP and mysql? I tried to check benchmark between long polling vs sse and it seems that SSE is better ? that is why i want to make a good choice....

Comment: `when he talk about 'Apache server and PHP+MySQL are not ideal for SSE' is he talking on a shared server`...that was my understanding yes. Although since PHP is not optimised for multi-threading you might find other disadvantages (compared to, say, nodeJS or ASP.NET where task-based asynchronous programming are native to the language), but I couldn't say 100%. As that video mentions, SSE is definitely more efficient than polling from the perspective of a single user. The problem is that, at scale, it has the potential to overwhelm the server with too many simultaneous, always-open connections

Comment: Thank you so much ADyson. I really appreciated your comments and your help with this issue! I will check to add a vote to your comments ! Thank you so much again ! Have a great day !